# RegExp Match only with paths contains filename

Tags: javascript, regex, file, match

I am trying to create a Regexp in JS that only look into string having files and ignore the paths which don't have a filename.

input

```
tanxe\src\lib\hello
tanxe\lib\hello\world\verboseBackup.js
tanxe\src\hello\verboseBackup.js
tanxe\lib\verboseBackup.js
```

Trying

```
input.match(/^tanxe.*?lib.*?\\..*/i)
```

Expected Output:

```
tanxe\lib\hello\world\verboseBackup.js
tanxe\lib\verboseBackup.js
```

Comment: Try `/^tanxe\\lib.*?\\.[^\\]*$/i`

Comment: @Wasim remove `^` to match line contains

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can try this mate**

```
^.*\.\w+$
```

> Explanation

- `^` - Anchor to start of string.
- `.*` - Matches anything one or more times except newline character.
- `\.` - Matches `.`.
- `\w+` - Matches word character one or more time.
- `$` - End  of string.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/NdkuQa/2)

**Update:-** **In case you strictly want to match tanxe\lib and followed things only**

**You can try this mate**

```
^tanxe\\lib\\.+\.\w+$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/NdkuQa/2)

Answer (score 1):

You might try this: `tanxe\\lib.*?\.\w+`
It matches paths starting with `tanxe\lib` and ending with a file extension.

Answer (score 1):

```
input.match(/^tanxe\\lib\\(\w+\\)*\w+\.\w+/gi);
```

See the [regExr](https://regexr.com/44ec7) fiddle I created.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex is work, I think you need is additional flags: `g` global, `m` multiline

```js
var input = `tanxe\\src\\lib\\hello
tanxe\\lib\\hello\\world\\verboseBackup.js
tanxe\\src\\hello\\verboseBackup.js
tanxe\\lib\\verboseBackup.js
D:\\Program Files\\atom\\.atom\\packages\\utilities-tanxe\\lib\\abc\\verboseBackup.js`

input.match(/^.*tanxe.*?lib.*?\..*/gmi).forEach(r => console.log(r))
// start with "tanxe"
//input.match(/^tanxe.*?lib.*?\..*/gmi).forEach(r => console.log(r))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one too.

```
 tanxe\\[a-zA-Z\\]+[.]{1}[a-zA-z]{2,3}
```